# JSON login with spring-lemon

Tags: json, authentication, spring-security, spring-lemon

I'm using spring-lemon for my web application project. Spring-lemon uses standard form login by default, which works fine. Now, however, I need to use authentication with json request, something like this:

```
{"username":"spring.user", "password":"s3cret"}
```

How should I achieve this safely? I've searched for it, and I've seen different solutions, but I couldn't use them with success.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Lemon doesn't come with this feature. However, I think you can code an end-point where you can manually fetch the user, match the password, decorate it and then set the authentication as below:

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, 
                user.getPassword(), user.getAuthorities()));
```

The [LemonTokenAuthenticationFilter](https://github.com/naturalprogrammer/spring-lemon/blob/master/src/main/java/com/naturalprogrammer/spring/lemon/security/LemonTokenAuthenticationFilter.java) does similar thing - you can have a look at it.